# Conditional probability of two values

Tags: probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I have a data set of two values, that can be true or false. Based on this I want to calculate what is the probability of happening B if A is true. I understand, that this should be calculated using Bayes' theorem, but I'm stuck with this.

Comment: Consider just the cases where $A$ is true.  What percentage of those also have $B$ true?  What percentage of those cases also have $B$ false?  You're done!

Comment: @david-g-stork And what I should do, if I have some numerical A's?

Comment: Take the value of $A$ of interest then count the percentage of $B$s that are true and the percentage of $B$s that are false.

Comment: @david-g-stork well, this makes sense. Thanks a lot.